# On the complexification of a Riemannian manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $TM$ be its tangent bundle. If we suppose $TM\otimes\mathbb{C}$ is the complexification of $TM$ then how can we define a natural metric on the complex bundle $TM \otimes\mathbb{C}$ as what there exists and how can we do the differentiation from the sections of this bundle by using the Levi-Civita connection of the metric $g$?

I mean If $X, Y$ are two sections of $TM \otimes\mathbb{C}$ then the inner product of $X, Y$ how can be defined by using the metric $g$?

Moreover, how can we differentiate from $X$ along $Y$ in a natural way by using the Levi-Civita connection of $g$?

I can not find a definition which describes such a metric and differentiation.

Comment: Your title mentions almost-complex manifolds, but your question doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each section of $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ has a unique decomposition $Z=X+iY$ as a sum with $X$ and $Y$ sections of $TM$. Define your metric using this, for example as $\left<Z_1,Z_2\right>=\left<X_1,X_2\right>+\left<Y_1,Y_2\right>$. Use an affine connection as $\nabla_{X+iY} U+iV=\nabla_X U - \nabla_Y V + i \left(\nabla_Y U + \nabla_X V\right)$ to get complex linearity.

Edit: the natural Hermitian metric on $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is $$\left<Z_1,Z_2\right>=\left<X_1,X_2\right>+\left<Y_1,Y_2\right>+i\left<Y_1,X_2\right>-i\left<X_1,Y_2\right>$$.

Comment: There's something odd about your metric: it's neither the hermitian nor the bilinear extension of $g$.  Of course, it's not clear what the OP wants.  Usually when people talk about complexifying the riemannian manifold, it means extending the metric complex-bilinearly.  This is then usually followed by a restricting it on some other real section of the complexified tangent bundle.

Comment: It is the real part of the Hermitian one, so it is a Riemannian metric, not complex-valued.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill I need the common definition such that in books is used. But I could not find a definition that describes such a metric and such a derivative.

Comment: @BenMcKay Are these definitions the common ones?

Comment: The are the common definitions, except that one usually uses Hermitian metrics on complex vector bundles.